Delete record and record associations based on multiple reference attributes
I have a join table that handles the logic of who owns what:
(Not final just my work in progress)
create_table :exercise_drills do |t|
  t.references :exercise, foreign_key: true, null: false
  t.references :drill, foreign_key: true, null: false
  t.references :organization, foreign_key: true, null: false
  t.bigint :exercise_drill_reference
  t.boolean :editable, default: false, null: false
  t.boolean :deleted, default: false, null: false
  t.boolean :exercise_deleted, default: false, null: false
  t.boolean :reference_deleted, default: false, null: false
  t.string :alt_name

  t.timestamps

  t.index [:exercise_id, :drill_id, :organization_id], unique: true, name: "index_guild_exercise_drill_uniqueness"
end

class ExerciseDrill < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :exercise
  belongs_to :drill
  belongs_to :organization
end

The basic logic of organization is that when it is deleted a method will run, (this is a basic draft not final):
class Organization < ApplicationRecord
  before_destroy :mark_exercise_delete

  # this may need to be nulify to deal with objects with exercises associations
  has_many :exercise_drills
  has_many :exercises, through: :exercise_drills, dependent: :restrict_with_exception

  private

  def mark_exercise_delete
    exercise_drills.find_each do |ed|
      ed.update_attribute(deleted: true)

      # could be solved using reference
      r_id = exercise_drills.pluck(:id)
      ExerciseDrill.where(exercise_drill_reference: r_id).find_each do |ed|
        update_attribute(exercise_deleted: true)
      end
    end
  end
end

class Drill < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :exercise_drill
  has_one :exercise, through: :exercise_drill
end

class Exercise < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :exercise_drill, dependent: :destroy
  has_one :drill, through: :exercise_drill
  delegate :alt_name, :editable?, to: :exercise_drill
end

Info on the method above for context:
The second part of this method exercise_drill_reference is here because the organization as the ability to copy the exercise drill but change the drill and add an alt name, the exercise will remain the same. To keep track if the record was copied I have editable which will be true if there is no exercise_reference, indicating it is a new exercise record. If it is not a new record it is false and exercise_reference is set with the exercise_drill_id being copied.
Now I'm trying to figure out how to handle the deletion of these records, what I have so far is to:
A: use this mark_exercise_delete boolean, once these 3 are true then they are deleted via a job that fires once a month or something that does something like:
def self.perform
  e = ExerciseDrill.where(deleted: true, exercise_deleted: true, reference_deleted: true)
  e.exercise.destroy
  e.destroy
end

B: instead of dependent: :destroy and on_delete: :cascade, it is instead dependent: :nullify, on_delete: :nullify. Then the job is changed to:
def self.perform
  ExerciseDrill.where(exercise_delete: true, organization: null, reference_deleted: true).destroy_all
end

or modify the table so that exercises_references is a reference, i.e. t.references :exercise_reference, to_table: :exercise_drill, on_delete: :nullify so i can do:
def self.perform
  ExerciseDrill.where(exercise_delete: true, organization: null, exercise_reference: null).destroy_all
end

What needs to happen if exercise_drill record is still in use:

If the exercise_drill is still in use, via exercise_id, the record is not destroyed.
If the organization is destroyed, but the exercise_drill is still in use, via exercise_id, the record is not destroyed.
If the exercise is destroyed, but the exercise_drill is still in use, via exercise_id, the record is not destroyed.
If the exercise_drill that it is refenced from, aka copied from, is destoyed, the record is not destroyed.

Side note, if organization is destroyed then the exercise, exercise_drill would not be in use so it could be safely destroyed. The issue is if the exercise_drill record is copied. If that is the main problem I'll re-design to get rid of this issue.
Once the exercise is no longer referenced, the record can be safely destroyed.
If the exercise_dill, via the exericse_id, is not in use:

If an organization is destroyed then the exercise_drill is
destroyed
If the exercise is destroyed then the exercise_drill is destroyed
If the exercise_drill that it is refenced from, aka copied from, is
destroyed then the record is destroyed.


It's very unclear what you're trying to accomplish here. In your schema you have t.references :organization, foreign_key: { on_delete: :cascade }, null: false which creates a database trigger that cascades to the other table and then you just have a maze of methods and callbacks. Are you trying to implement a soft delete?

Focus less on the existing code and tell us what it that should be expected to happen when a record is deleted.

@max ya I know the schema has cascade in it this was kind of my "get columns in" that I know I need, then update the migration once I build out models and controllers. Had not though about deleting records that were still needed yet. It looks like I'm going to have to implement a form of soft delete yes. Still want the records destroyed once it is no longer referenced; i.e. referenced record was destroyed. Question has been updated.

You can't really combine non-nullable foreign keys, cascades and callback madness to reach that goal. If you want a soft-delete then implement a real soft delete and then use a ActiveJob to clean up periodically. If you want to be able to orphan records on purpose  you need to remove the constraints.

In general remove all the denormalized duplicate columns like exercise_deleted  and just add deleted_at datetime columns (boolean are baaad) to the tables that should be soft deleteable so that you can schedule deletion. There are also numerious gems that add soft delete features to rails.

@max can you give a link or reason why the boolean is bad please. Also, if I'm getting rid of the constraint, should I also just remove the index that is default true with reference?

Because boolean state flags only capture one thing when you could actually record something meaningful. The index doesn't actually matter that much unless its a unique index (which would prevent multiple nulls).
